# Add one with same foreign key at row sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem on sql server.

How to get running number from foreign key in one time select data from table?

example :
I have one table such as

```
 -----------------
| id | pid | desc |
 -----------------
|  1 |  1  |   a  |
|  2 |  1  |   b  |
|  3 |  1  |   c  |
|  4 |  2  |   d  |
|  5 |  2  |   e  |
|  6 |  2  |   f  |
|  7 |  2  |   g  |
|  8 |  3  |   h  |
|  9 |  3  |   i  |
| 10 |  1  |   j  |
| 11 |  1  |   k  |
 -----------------
```

I want to get result as below

```
 ------------------------
| id | pid | desc | rec  |
 ------------------------
|  1 |  1  |   a  |   1  |
|  2 |  1  |   b  |   2  |
|  3 |  1  |   c  |   3  |
|  4 |  2  |   d  |   1  |
|  5 |  2  |   e  |   2  |
|  6 |  2  |   f  |   3  |
|  7 |  2  |   g  |   4  | 
|  8 |  3  |   h  |   1  |
|  9 |  3  |   i  |   2  |
| 10 |  1  |   j  |   4  |
| 11 |  1  |   K  |   5  |
 ------------------------
```

In above tables foreign key ('pid') Column has values 1 to 3 in different row numbers.
I tried to get the running number from each 'pid' field name.
I havn't found any way to do this,

Can I do that? Can some one help me? am still newbie at sql server

Comment: Please post structure of both table you are looking to join and highlight the foreign keys if it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
id,
pid,
[desc],
Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY id) AS rec
FROM <yourtable>
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ranking function in SQL Server 2005+ to accomplish that,

So here is your query

```
Select Row_Number() over (partition by pid order by id) as rec , * from Table
```